# D3JS - Can I make a force-directed graph with individual nodes and how?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Question: Is it possible for me to make each node individually, and then use the force layout to connect them? If not, how would I go about pre-placing the nodes? And if so, can I get some help with the syntax, please?

Context: I am new to D3, and am trying to make a force-directed graph for only five nodes as part of the landing page for an academic project. I am using [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) example and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/11550728) example, and sort of want to make a combination of the two by putting my nodes in the arrays.

For example, could I do something like:

```
        var w = 1300;
        var h = 10000;
        //An area for svg elements
        var svgArea = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        //All the node definitions
        var nodeMain = svgArea.append("a")
            .attr("height", 300)
            .attr("width", 300)
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 300)
            .attr("cx", 650)
            .attr("cy", 700)
            .attr("fill", "orange");

        var nodeMedia = svgArea.append("a")
            .attr("height", 200)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 200)
            .attr("cx", 250)
            .attr("cy", 1150)
            .attr("fill", "orange");

        var nodeRef = svgArea.append("a")
            .attr("height", 200)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 200)
            .attr("cx", 1050)
            .attr("cy", 1150)
            .attr("fill", "orange");

        //Nodes for the visualization
        var nodes = [nodeMain, nodeMedia, nodeRef];

        //Connected using indices of the array
        var edges = [{source: 1, target: 0}, {source: 2, target: 0}];

        //Force-directed
        var connect = d3.layout.force()
            .size([w, h])
            .gravity(1)             
            .distance(100)
            .charge(-50);

        connect.nodes(nodes).links(edges);

        var orb = svgArea.selectAll(".node").data(nodes)
            .enter().append("g")    
            .call(force.drag);


        var link = svgArea.selectAll(".link").data(edges)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

        connect.on("tick", function(){
            link.attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x})
                .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y})
                .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.source.x})
                .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.source.y});

            orb.attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
        });

        connect.start();
```

(And in the event I asked a really silly question, would anyone mind directing me to some D3 resources where I can learn more of the concepts/syntax without emulating/relying purely on examples?)

Thank you in advance, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made slight changes in your code snippet and added necessary comments. Share your queries if any.

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 500;

//An area for svg elements
var svgArea = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

//Nodes for the visualization
var nodes = [{
  name: "Main",
  x: 80,
  y: 10
}, {
  name: "Media",
  x: 15,
  y: 40
}, {
  name: "Reference",
  x: 60,
  y: 60
}];

//Connected using indices of the array
var edges = [{
  source: 1,
  target: 0
}, {
  source: 2,
  target: 0
}];

//Force-directed
var connect = d3.layout.force()
  .size([w, h])
  .gravity(1)
  .distance(150)
  .charge(-200);

connect
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(edges);

//Creating links
var link = svgArea.selectAll(".link")
  .data(edges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke", "black");

//Creating nodes
var orb = svgArea.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node");  

orb.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", "orange");

//Adding Labels
orb.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });
  
//Adding images
orb.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
  .attr("x", -10)
  .attr("y", -10)
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20);
  
orb.on("click",function(d){
  alert("clicked "+d.name);
});

connect.on("tick", function() {

  //Updating the link positions during force simulation.
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y
    });

  //Updating the node position during force simulation  
  orb.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});

connect.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

D3 has a rich documentation which is available here: [GitHub](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/kv05y1hq/

Comment: Thank you so much! Am I able to set their locations beforehand? Or do I not have a choice in where each node shows up when I use the force-directed layout? Is it feasible to customize each node?

Comment: You can set static x, y positions for each node.  Try running the code snippet repeatedly. You can see that the nodes come at same positions each time you execute.

Comment: Customization of each node is also possible. If you have a very few number of nodes, you can create them separately without using d3 enter selections. (Directly append each node). I will share a sample fiddle for customizing each node with d3 enter selections.

Comment: Updated the fiddle link in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's of any help I have the following Plunkers...

http://plnkr.co/edit/TiKKmvydqXNipe103juL?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSmvH05nnAD6cYZb0EM4?p=preview

The first one is to show/hide groups of elements when clicked on.

The second is to demonstrate drag/zoom.

Also the data is externalised into a json file and read in using...

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
```

This should enable you to reduce your node definitions down to one function.